# Locate the file generating a compilation error from terminal output

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling

Consider the following files:

`test1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{test2}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

`test2.tex`:

```
\usepackage{badpak}
```

In MikTeX with:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test
```

I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo")) (test2.tex)

! LaTeX Error: File `badpak.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.3 \begin
          {document}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

If I move the error to the `test1.tex`

`test1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{test2}
\usepackage{badpak}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

`test2.tex`:

```
\relax
```

I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo")) (test2.tex)

! LaTeX Error: File `badpak.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.4 \begin
          {document}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

The two outputs is almost identical:
*how can I tell which is the file the error comes from?*

I have also tried the options `-file-line-error` and  `-c-style-errors`, but without better results.
Also the transcript written on `test.log` does not help.

Comment: Is `! LaTeX Error: File `badpak.sty' not found.` not indicative of the error? Also, is `\usepackage{badpak}` actually the extent of the second file?

Comment: @JefferyShivers: we are interested in the location of the error, not the error itself and there is not hint in the output about which file is `\usepackage{badpak}` located.

Answer (score 6):

when TeX opens a file for input it adds `(` to the log and when it closes it it adds `)` so you can tell which file is open at the point the error is detected by seeing which file path is by the nearest unmatched `(`.

In both cases here the error is *detected* in the top level input file.

If you use

test1.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{test2}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

test2.tex

```
\usepackage{badpak}\relax
```

you get

```
(./test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./test2.tex

! LaTeX Error: File `badpak.sty' not found.
```

where the unmatched `(` before `./test2.tex` shows that file is open.

In your case you were in the unlucky but very unusual case of the input file ending with a command (`\usepackage`) that has a trailing optional argument that is not present. So the command looks ahead to see if there is a trailing `[` starting a `[2016/01/01]` argument, and in doing so it hits the end of file and triggers the file to be closed, so it is closed *before* latex executes the body of `\usepackage` and finds the file is missing, so you see

```
(test2.tex)

! LaTeX Error: File `badpak.sty' not found.
```

where the error is reported immediately *after* the `)` denoting that `test2.tex` has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make your compilation more verbose using `\message`:

```
\newcommand{\myinput}[1]{\message{[START input of #1}\input{#1}\message{END input of #1]}}
\myinput{test2}
```