# How to avoid \input files being displayed in the terminal output?

Tags: compiling, input, warnings, terminal-output

As indicated in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316779/5471 , files with content included via the `\input` command are displayed as `(file)` on the terminal output. Assume there are specific files, the inclusion of which I don't want to see broadcasted in the output. How can I define a new `\myinput` that will be doing the same thing as `\input` without calls to `\message`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myinput}[1]{\input{#1}}
\begin{document}
a
\message{I input a file:} \input{b.tex}
c
\message{Nothing to see here} \myinput{b.tex}
\end{document}
```

My motivation is that I use the package `comment` and whenever I include some comment, I get a `(./comment.cut)` displayed in the output.

Comment: `\batchmode` ? the `(....)` does not come from any user-configurable message it comes from the heart of tex-the-program so all you can do is turn off all output (unless you are using luatex)

Comment: I didn't really know `\batchmode`. It seems that it also removes useful warnings. Oh well. I might have to live with `(...)` then.  Feel free to turn your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (....) does not come from any user-configurable message it comes from the heart of tex-the-program so all you can do is turn off all output (unless you are using luatex)

You can use `\batchmode` to turn off all terminal output, either for the whole document or by setting it locally just around your input (then returning to errorstopmode or scrollmode afterwards)